# How to fix error: Plugin with id 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' not found

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have looked around to solve this error and still haven't found any solution.

I have tried switching to other google-services versions and not including any version at all but none have worked. No solution found online have fixed the problem either.

My build.gradle (Project) code is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle (Module: app) code is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.whatsappclone"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: add only like this in your app level gradle, i mean remove version =>  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: @android Thank you for your response. If I remove the version number it shows me an error on the following line about mixing versions =>  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps that can help you:

**1. First of all downgrade your "com.android.tools.build:gradle" version from "3.4.0" to "3.3.2"**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**2. Open "gradle-wrapper.properties" and update your distributionUrl url as below with "5.1.1-all" version**

```
#Mon May 06 12:26:03 IST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

**3. Open "gradle.properties" and add below two lines**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**4. Then update your app level gradle as below:**

The problem is you used this sign ":" instead of "." for apply "google-services"

Wrong plugin implementation => apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services'

Right plugin implementation => apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

> Final Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ankit.gradletest511"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this just gave me a whole lot of errors in the main java code probably because the versions are not matching!

Comment: they can be import statements. right? For example you have to import "androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity" instead of "android.support.v7.app.appcompatactivity" because we are using androix library instead of support appcomart library